# Override rake release task to use Gemfury

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rakefile

I'm hosting a private gem on [Gemfury](http://www.gemfury.com/) and would like to override `rake release` task to push to my Gemfury private URL instead of Rubygems.

I'de like to keep the Git tag creation though.

Any ideas where I should begin to?

Here is what my Rakefile looks like:

```
require 'bundler/gem_tasks'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)

task default: :spec
task test:    :spec
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually found the answer:

**Rakefile**

```
require 'bundler/gem_tasks'
require 'rubygems/builder'
require 'gemfury'
require 'gemfury/command'

# Override rubygem_push to push to gemfury instead when doing `rake release`
module Bundler
  class GemHelper
    def rubygem_push(path)
      ::Gemfury::Command::App.start(['push', path])
    end
  end
end
```

Now when doing:

```
rake release
```

It create git tags and push to my Gemfury private gem repository.

You'll want to create a file in `~/.gem/gemfury` with your secret key:

```
---
:gemfury_api_key: 1H...
```

Comment: Is there any way to specify the gemfury_api_key on the command line? I'd like to have Jenkins doing a build and push of my gem, and don't much fancy having the secret in the source code somewhere.

Comment: This is [how it is implemented](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb#L82). I don't think what you want to achieve is possible.

Comment: Thanks - I only realised later that the `.gem` directory doesn't make it into the packaged gem, which was my main concern.

Comment: Ah - on my Jenkins box I'm getting `cannot load such file -- rubygems/builder` when executing the Rakefile. Any ideas why? I'm thinking maybe my version of RubyGems is too old?

Comment: This is a very nice solution you put together and I plan on using it.  The only thing that occurred to me is that it's a bit risky to depend on the internals of Bundler since this is a protected method, and if there is a refactoring at a higher level this could disappear out from under you, leading to accidentally pushing a private gem to rubygems.org.  What I did is to include this guard `raise "Bundler::GemHelper#rubygem_push method not found !!! monkeypatch repair needed" unless Bundler::GemHelper.instance_methods.include?(:rubygem_push)`

Comment: Also fwiw I added `desc "Modified to push to Gemfury";
task :release` so that rake -T shows that it is not a stock bundler task.